# Placing a JavaFX Applet into an HTML Page

Tags: applet, javafx

How can I place a JavaFX applet into an html page that doesn't use SUN's Javascript?

```
<script src="http://dl.javafx.com/1.2/dtfx.js"></script>
```

I.e. I want something like

```
<APPLET CODE="AppletSubclass.class" ARCHIVE="file1, file2"
    WIDTH=anInt HEIGHT=anInt></APPLET>
```

I tried using the `com.sun.javafx.runtime.adapter.Applet` class in my script, but I didn't understand how to use it because it hasn't any appropriate instance variables to hold a scene.
This is my test script:
![alt text][1]

https://s47.radikal.ru/i115/0907/5a/60e5f3be9aa3.png

I'm using JavaFX version 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_where_is_applet_tag). There you can see the applet tag which is generated by the javascript. Though it uses JNLP and not the old-fashioned applet style.
Does this help? By the way, why don't you want to use the JS?

EDIT: See this article http://blogs.oracle.com/mobility_techtips/entry/how_to_develop_and_run about how to run applets in a closed intranet. As you will see its not very convenient, and comments show that people are not really happy with it. But it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a bit. I don't want use JS because I need some control over applet html element. Also applet will be placed on intranet site and users may have no access to SUN's resource. 
But anyway, thanks.

Comment: ok, so that only helps to avoid the JS. The other part could be a problem. I don't know if you can still run an applet without access to the internet. If you find out, tell me.

Comment: Found an article which should solve the problem of running the applet without internet access. I updated my answer.